# How to use custom tables in Views

Tags: 7, views

I have multisite DRUPAL6.26 website using VIEWS 3.0 module in it.

Both sites are install in single DB.
The first/parent site has no prefix for its tables.EX: node,block,role etc..
The second/childsite has prefix of child. EX: child_node,child_block,child_role etc..

I have a VIEW showing all pictures uploaded by user in there PARENT site account.
And the same VIEW for CHILD site showing pictures that they upload on CHILD site.

**What I want is to show all pictures in PARENT site account of user whether they upload on PARENT site OR CHILD site.**
[users are shared between the 2 sites.]

Any help of 'views master' required :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a hook for exposing custom fields to Views: [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs!docs.php/function/hook_views_data/6)

> Describe table structure to Views.
>
> This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be auto-loaded. This must either be in the same directory as the .module file or in a subdirectory named 'includes'.
>
> The full documentation for this hook is in the advanced help.

The link also includes example code.